# Rails wikedPDF Error: PDF could not be generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use WickedPdf on rails 6 but I'm having this error

```
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
["/home/guilherme/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20200531-14069-p9pvre.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20200531-14069-8mk29k.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /home/guilherme/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf:45:in `<top (required)>': Invalid platform, must be running on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04/18.04 CentOS 6/7/8, Debian 8/9/10, or intel-based macOS (missing binary: /home/guilherme/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf_ubuntu_20.04_amd64). (RuntimeError)
    from /home/guilherme/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf:23:in `load'
    from /home/guilherme/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf:23:in `<main>'
):
```

in my gemfile i add

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

my controller method to render pdf is

```
  def gera_contrato
    cliente = Cliente.find_by_id(params[:cliente])
    @cnpj = cliente.local.cnpj
    @razao = cliente.local.razao
    @fantasia = cliente.local.fantasia
    @nome = cliente.nome
    @cpf = cliente.cpf
    @rg = cliente.rg
    render pdf: 'contrato', handlers: [:erb], formats: [:html]
  end
```

my html file to pdf is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf" -%>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= @cnpj %></h1>
    <h1><%= @razao %></h1>
    <h1><%= @fantasia %></h1>
    <h1><%= @nome %></h1>
    <h1><%= @cpf %></h1>
    <h1><%= @rg %></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I already changed the paths, changed gem versions, and did a lot of things but nothing worked, what should I do to solve this error?

Comment: What operating system are trying to run this on?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is your problem. The error message states: `Invalid platform, must be running on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04/18.04`. You'll have to install the version for Ubuntu 20.04 from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and manually point it to this version like this

/config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

```rb
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/path/to/correct/version'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6.5'
```

**Option 2:**

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g fontconfig libxrender1 libfreetype6 libxext6 libx11-6 

sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Use the latest version for ubuntu 22.04 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6.6'

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, and after doing some research I found the issue is due to `wkhtmltopdf-binary`, which was not compatible with Ubuntu 21.04 (in my case). Found the solution [here.](https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem/issues/62)

Comment: Sorry, this answer does not provide anything new, when compared to the already accepted answer.

Comment: I do not see the difference, except that your answer has less information. It is almost a link-only answer.